# Modelado de un sistema

Tags: java

Tengo que entregar el siguiente ejercicio y no se por donde empezar, es decir la parte de los valores minimos maximos y promedio no tengo problema pero en las condiciones que me ponen sobre que al sistema se le envian 8 lecturas por segundo pero sin enbargo por problemas de hardawe el solo puede procesar informacion 2 veces  por minuto es  lo que no entiendo. Me parece que los tiros van por HILOS pero no he leido aun mucho al respecto me gustaria no que me lo hicieran pero si que me orienten por donde puedo empezar a leer o que me falta, que me marquen el norte, mucho les sabre agradecer. Ya me he leido sobre interface, polimorfismos, clases abstractas, librerias y clases de java pero no encuentro nada que me de una idea de como resolver esa parte. A continuacion el enunciado.

Existen 4 sensores en un sistema que miden un valor numérico y deben enviarlo para su procesamiento. El sistema de monitoreo, toma estos valores y calcula tres parámetros:
promedio, valor máximo y valor mínimo buscando alguna de las siguientes anomalías:
● La diferencia entre el valor mínimo y máximo recibido sea mayor a una constante S (configurable)
● El valor promedio sea superior a una constante M (configurable)
En caso de detectar alguna de las situaciones mencionadas en los puntos anteriores, debe mostrar por pantalla un mensaje de error indicando esta situación.
Es importante tener en cuenta que:
● Los sensores envían 2 mediciones por segundo (en forma independiente y
potencialmente simultánea).
● El sistema de procesamiento, por limitaciones de hardware, sólo puede procesar
información 2 veces por minuto.
● Se debe respetar el orden de ingreso de los mensajes al sistema de monitoreo.
● Todos los mensajes recibidos deben ser loggeados asi como también registrar
información al momento de su procesamiento.
En Java, desarrolle un programa que se ejecute desde consola y que modele este sistema.

```
package evaluacionadistancia;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

/**
 * Clase creada para definir el comportamiento del sistema de procesamiento 
 * 
 * @author marco
 */
public class SistemaProcesamiento  {
    /*creamos una variable bufferDatos de donde se van a leer y escribir los datos que entran al 
      sistema, esta varible va a ser de tipo ArrayList, no se pueden usar datos primitivos
    */
    private static int rangoAleatorio=11;
    private static int variableS=0;
    private static int variableM=0;
    private double valorPromedio;
    private int valorMax;
    private int valorMin;
    private ArrayList<Integer> bufferDatos = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> bufferDatosCopia = new ArrayList<>();
    private static SistemaProcesamiento sistema = new SistemaProcesamiento();
    /*
    Creo tambien un objeto de la clase SecureRandom para generar numeros aleatoreos, 
    */
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    //creo los metodos de la clase a partir de esta linea
    public void procesarData(){
        if((this.valorMax-this.valorMin)>this.variableS){
            System.out.println("->Precaucion.... Diferencia entre Vmax y Vmin es mayor que "
                    + "S:"+this.variableS);

        } 
        if(this.valorPromedio>this.variableM){
            System.out.println("->Precaucion.... VPromedio es mayor que M:"+this.variableM);
        }

    }
    public void calcularValorMinimo(){
        //declaramos las variables a usar en este metodo
        int valorMinimo = this.valorMax;
        //Aqui vamos a valcular valor maximo
        Iterator<Integer> iterador = this.bufferDatosCopia.iterator();
        while(iterador.hasNext()){
            int elemento = iterador.next();
            if(elemento<valorMinimo){
                valorMinimo = elemento;
            }

        }
        this.valorMin = valorMinimo;
        System.out.println("->Imprimiendo valor minimo");
        System.out.println(this.valorMin);
    }
    public void calcularValorMaximo(){
        //declaramos las variables a usar en este metodo
        int valorMaximo=0;
        //Aqui vamos a valcular valor maximo
        Iterator<Integer> iterador = this.bufferDatosCopia.iterator();
        while(iterador.hasNext()){
            int elemento = iterador.next();
            if(elemento>valorMaximo){
                valorMaximo = elemento;
            }

        }
        this.valorMax = valorMaximo;
        System.out.println("->Imprimiendo valor maximo");
        System.out.println(this.valorMax);

    }
    public void calcularValorPromedio(){
        //declaramos las variables a usar en este metodo
        int suma=0;
        //Aqui vamos a calcular el valor promedio
        Iterator<Integer> iterador = this.bufferDatosCopia.iterator();
        while(iterador.hasNext()){
            int elemento = iterador.next();
            suma = suma+elemento;
        }
        valorPromedio =(double) suma/this.bufferDatosCopia.size();
        System.out.println("->Imprimiendo valor promedio");
        System.out.println(this.valorPromedio);

    }

    /**
     * @param range Es es rango de valores aleatoreos que queremos se escriban, desde 0 al numero 
     * escrito excluyendolo, es decir uno menos que el numero indicado.
    */
    public void writeProcess(int range){
        //el 11 indica que los numeros van desde 0 a uno menos es decir 10

            int valorGenerado = random.nextInt(range);
            bufferDatos.add(valorGenerado);


    }

    /**
     * Setter para seleccionar el rango de los numeros aleatoreos que se van a estar generando en los 
     * sensores
     * @param rango Rango de numeros que se van a estar leyendo, desde 0 (incluyente) hasta rango
     * (excluyente)
     */
    public void setRangoAleatorio(int rango){
        SistemaProcesamiento.rangoAleatorio = rango;

    }
    /**
     * setter para seleccionar el valor de la  variable m, En este sistema se activara un mensaje
     * si el valor promedio es mayor que M
     * @param m 
     */
    public  void setVariableM(int m){
        SistemaProcesamiento.variableM = m;
    }
    /**
     * setter para seleccionar el valor de la variable s, En este sistema se activara un mensaje si
     * la diferencia entre el valor maximo y el valor minimo es mayor que S
     * @param s 
     */
    public void setVariableS(int s){
        SistemaProcesamiento.variableS = s;

    }

    public void readProcess(){
        this.bufferDatosCopia = (ArrayList) bufferDatos.clone();
        bufferDatos.clear();
    }
    /**
     * Metodo que imprime los elementos de una arraylist
     * @param array  ArrayList a imprimir
     */
    private static void printBufferMethod(ArrayList array){
        //creacion de un Iterator para ejecutar las operaciones de lectura del ArrayList
        Iterator<Integer> iterador = array.iterator();
        while(iterador.hasNext()){
            int elemento = iterador.next();
            System.out.print(elemento+"/");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void printBufferCopia(){
        printBufferMethod(this.bufferDatosCopia);
    }

    //A partir de aqui la creacion de las clases anidadas
    private static class TaskReadProcess implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            synchronized(sistema){
                System.out.println("->Leyendo...");
                sistema.readProcess();
            }

            System.out.println("->Imprimiendo BufferDatosCopia");
            sistema.printBufferCopia();
            sistema.calcularValorPromedio();
            sistema.calcularValorMaximo();
            sistema.calcularValorMinimo();
            sistema.procesarData();
        }

    }

    private static class TaskWriteProcess implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            synchronized(sistema){
                System.out.println("->Escribiendo...");
                sistema.writeProcess(rangoAleatorio);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);


        SistemaProcesamiento sistema = new SistemaProcesamiento();
        sistema.bufferDatos.clear();
        sistema.bufferDatosCopia.clear();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el valor de la variable S");
        int varS = entrada.nextInt();
        sistema.setVariableS(varS);

        System.out.println("Introduzca el valor de la variable M");
        int varM = entrada.nextInt();
        sistema.setVariableM(varM);

        System.out.println("Introduzca el valor del rango Max de los valores captados por los "
                + "sensores");
        int varSensor = entrada.nextInt();
        sistema.setRangoAleatorio(varSensor+1);

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new TaskWriteProcess(), 0L, 500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new TaskWriteProcess(), 0L, 500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new TaskWriteProcess(), 0L, 500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new TaskWriteProcess(), 0L, 500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new TaskReadProcess(), 30L, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }

}
```

Comment: me temo que si no muestras un avance significativo, esto va a terminar cerrado

Comment: Como comenta @element, si no subes el código de lo que tienes hecho, o no pones una duda específica, va a ser muy difícil que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: En el sitio te sugerimos realizar preguntas en base a [ask].

Comment: La pregunta en si es como comienzo, coloque todo el ejercicio para que se entendiera de manera general, la parte que me tranca el inicio es que el sistema  captura las variables por los 4 sensores dos veces por segundo pero solo pueden ser procesada la informacion 2 veces por minuto. no se si aqui se trabajan con retardos, contadores o cosas por el estilo.  Pero saben que tienen razon, voy a ir haciendo avances, comenzare por la parte de procesamiento de la informacion que si tengo idea de como hacerlo y pues llegado el punto vemos como enfocar lo que me tranca. Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Ya hice gran parte del ejercicio, me sirvio mucho la ayuda  de @ÁlvaroSánchez, ahora el tema esta en si me pueden orientar un poco con la parte de como como loggear los mensajes. ● Todos los mensajes recibidos deben ser loggeados asi como también registrar información al momento de su procesamiento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder realizar este tipo de operaciones te recomiendo que uses los ScheduledExecutorService de java 8, a continuación te muestro un ejemplo sencillo accediendo varios hilos a una misma lista.

```
public class App {
private static List<Double> valores = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(addValue(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(readValue(), 30, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static Runnable addValue() {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Añadiendo valor");
            valores.add(Math.random()*10);
        }
    };

}
private static Runnable readValue(){
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Double double1 : valores) {
                System.out.println(double1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Gracias amigo Alvaro, todo el dia de hoy la pasare escribiendo codigo con esto, muchas gracias por tu aporte. Ya estoy haciendo la primera parte del programa y al finalizar veo como lo combio con esta parte, bueno primero a leer lo que hacen estas clases claro esta.

Comment: Perfecto compañero, el metodo scheduleWithFixedDelay ejecuta una funcion en el periodo de tiempo que le digamos a través de un nuevo hilo, tengo dudas si puede haber problemas de concurrencias he estado depurando y he descubierto que si un hilo accede a la lista el otro hilo se para hasta que este finalice, de todos modos coméntame lo que sea... No se te olvide ponerme el tick verde :)

Comment: La idea que me da la clase a la que haces referencia es que como van a llegar 8 datos en un segundo y solo puedo procesar 2 veces en un minuto, es decir 1 vaz cada 30 segundos. Seria colocar un delay de 30 segundos que simule esta condicion y tratar de procesar en ese segundo el maximo numero de operaciones correcto? o se puede configurar para que simule la cantidad de hilos suficientes para atender a ese numero de opereciones que se puedan sar en esos 30 segundos. que serian 8 * 30 = 240?